# Formatting output from powershell

Tags: powershell

I have this script (below) that I need to format the output from so that it appends a word + the date. Can you help?

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_PerfFormattedData_W3SVC_WebService -ComputerName SERVERNAME | Where {$_.Name -eq "WEBURL"} | % {$_. CurrentConnections}
```

I would like the output to be similar to this and append so that data is not overwritten.

(output from script) + "connected users" + date/time

**note** I was using, `Export-Csv c:\scripts\log.txt -encoding "unicode" -force` but that does not give desired results.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_PerfFormattedData_W3SVC_WebService -ComputerName SERVERNAME | 
    Where {$_.Name -eq "WEBURL"} | 
    Foreach {"$($_.CurrentConnections) connected users $(Get-Date)"}
```